# Find all the actors that made more movies with Christopher Nolan than any other director

Tags: mysql, sql

i need to find the actor that made more movies with nolan than any other director.

'This query will give me movie directed by Christopher Nolan'

```
  select P1.PID, P1.Name,
   Movie.MID 
   from Person P1 natural join M_Cast natural 
  join Movie join M_Director on (Movie.MID = M_Director.MID) join Person P2 on (M_Director.PID = P2.PID) where P2.Name='Christopher Nolan'
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2NAp.jpg

Comment: You need a GROUP BY to COUNT().

Comment: select P1.PID, P1.Name,
   Movie.MID 
   from Person P1 natural join M_Cast natural 
  join Movie join M_Director on (Movie.MID = M_Director.MID) join Person P2 on (M_Director.PID = P2.PID) where P2.Name='Christopher Nolan' group by P1.PID having count(Movie.MID) --this one

Comment: Tip of today, forget about the NATURAL JOIN. Do regular JOIN and specify the join conditions!

Comment: but i have to find actor that made more movie with this director than any other director means movies by nolan > movies not by nolan

Comment: Do you know that you can [edit] your question? Your SQL query should not be in a comment.

Comment: someone has already edited it

Comment: Are you allowed to post the structures of the database tables `Person`, `M_Cast`, `Movie` and `M_Director`?

Comment: Could you include your table specifications? The relation between the various entities is not really clear .

Comment: i have updated image

Comment: natural join are error prone to use i would suggest avoiding then, imagine what happen if you add a new column in both tables with the same name then your join condition also changed.

Comment: What happens if an actor made 4 movies. 2 with Nolan and 2 with Spielberg? Does that match?

Comment: then just give that count of movie with nolan

Comment: Doesn't make sense. You wants the actors names or some kind of count?

Comment: actor name with count of movies they made with nolan

Comment: select p.name from Person p join M_Cast c on c.PID=p.pid Join Movie 
where (select Count(Movie.mid) from Person P1 Left join M_Cast natural join Movie join M_Director on (Movie.MID = M_Director.MID) 
join Person P2 on (M_Director.PID = P2.PID) 
where P2.Name='Christopher Nolan' group by P1.PID 
having count(Movie.MID)
>
(select Count(Movie.mid) from Person P3 Left join M_Cast natural join Movie join M_Director on (Movie.MID = M_Director.MID) 
join Person P4 on (M_Director.PID = P4.PID) 
where P2.Name!='Christopher Nolan' group by P4.PID))

Comment: You did it again: edit your question instead of adding your query as a comment

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained. Insert images/links using edit functions. Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. What parts are you able to do? Where are you stuck? What did your textbook or the documentation say about anything relevant? Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL which includes constraints & indexes & base table initialization.

Comment: Your title/question doesn't make sense. Do you mean, 'find the actors that made more movies with Christopher Nolan than any director'? (Actors plural & drop the 'other' before 'director'.) (Note that 'more than any director' means more than all directors.) PS This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really test it, but something similar to this should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
        SELECT   actor.name AS ActorName,
                 COUNT(CASE UPPER(dirct.name) WHEN 'CHRISTOPHER NOLAN' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS WithNolan,
                 COUNT(CASE UPPER(dirct.name) WHEN 'CHRISTOPHER NOLAN' THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) AS NotNolan
        FROM     movie
        JOIN     m_cast
          ON     movie.mid = m_cast.mid
        JOIN     person actor
          ON     m_cast.pid = actor.pid
        JOIN     m_director
          ON     movie.mid = m_director.mid
        JOIN     person dirct
          ON     m_director.pid = dirct.pid
        GROUP BY actor.name
       )
WHERE  WithNolan > NotNolan;
```

Comment: If you show us your data set we might be able to check

Comment: Try without the WHERE-clause and see the results

Comment: trying without where clause, getting same result

Comment: Then show us the data set. Apparently there are no movies with both actors and a director

Comment: Updated the answer to make it case-insensitive